# How do I get the width and height from a tab control?

Tags: c, winapi, window, height, width

I have a tab control where I'd like to get its width and height to create a window that fills this area.
But I don't quite get how to get this width and height. From what I found, the value get from `TabCtrl_GetItemRect()` is in dialog-unit, so I need to convert to pixels, the I would do for example `int width = tr.right - tr.left` but that value is wrong, if I pass that value to the `CreateWindowExW()` it creates a tiny control, that's not even 1/4 of the target width and height. The routine I'm using to convert from dialog-unit to pixel is:

```
void DlgUnitsToPxs(RECT *rect)
{
  long units = GetDialogBaseUnits();
  int xBaseUnit = LOWORD(units);
  int yBaseUnit = HIWORD(units);

  rect->left   = MulDiv(rect->left,   xBaseUnit, 4);
  rect->right  = MulDiv(rect->right,  xBaseUnit, 4);
  rect->top    = MulDiv(rect->top,    yBaseUnit, 8);
  rect->bottom = MulDiv(rect->bottom, yBaseUnit, 8);
}
```

getting the values like this:

```
RECT tr = {0};
TabCtrl_GetItemRect(hTabControl, 0, &tr);
DlgUnitsToPxs(&tr);
int width = tr.right - tr.left;
int height = tr.bottom - tr.top;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Use [`MapDialogRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapdialogrect), instead, and you won't have to worry about the dialog font.

Comment: That wouldn't work for `hTabControl` because it's a window and `MapDialogRect` needs a handle create with one of the dialog functions.

Comment: The question suggests the tab is used as a child control of a dialog box, in which case `MapDialogRect` would work, in fact better than the manual `GetDialogBaseUnits` calculation.

Comment: I switch from using the tab as children and made them siblings because I was told that's not how it's done and how that made TAB key doesn't work with those controls. See here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191015-00/?p=102996  I've tested `MapDialogRect()` before but it set `GetLastError()` to invalid handle. I'm trying out SoronelHaetir's approach. It doesn't fill the window as it should, I'm trying to figure out why before give him feedback

Comment: The tab control itself is still a child of the dialog, and it's the handle of the parent dialog that MapDialogRect expects. Whether you still need that after reparenting the (grand)child controls is another question.

Comment: I made the tab control itself child of the dialog but the dialog isn't created with one of the create dialog functions (can I create without resources?) so MapDialogRect return an invalid handle.

Comment: It is technically possible to create a dialog without a resource template, but it would be strange to create a dialog without using one of the functions that can create a dialog. Some code could help clarifying.

Comment: @dxiv You're right, this isn't a dialog box as I said, I was wrong. It's a regular windows actually, created with `CreateWindowEx()`. I remember I couldn't create this dialog box without resources so I ended up using just a window.

Comment: [`TabCtrl_GetItemRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-tabctrl_getitemrect) Retrieves the bounding rectangle for **a tab** in a tab control. if you want to create a tabbed dialog box, you could check [How to Create a Tabbed Dialog Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-a-tabbed-dialog-box)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the GetClientRect function and the TCM_ADJUSTRECT message (with wParam set to TRUE and an lParam being a pointer to the RECT to adjust). I generally create the windows that are going to be shown as tab children with the tab as the actual parent window just so that I then do not need to use MapWindowPoints on that RECT.

For example (although I would generally actually use C++ style initialization):

```
...
case WM_SIZE:
 {
  RECT rc;
  TCITEM item;
  HWND hWndChild;
  HWND hWndTab = GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_TAB);
  _ASSERT(hWndTab);

  item.mask = TCIF_PARAM;
  SendMessage(hWndTab, TCM_GETITEM, SendMessage(hWndTab, TCM_GETCURFOCUS, 0, 0), &item);

  _ASSERT(item.lParam);
  hWndChild = (HWND)item.lParam;

  GetClientRect(hWndTab, &rc);
  SendMessage(hWndTab, TCM_ADJUSTRECT, TRUE, (LPARAM)&rc);

  SetWindowPos(hWndChild, nullptr, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom, SWP_NOACTIVATE|SWP_NOMOVE);
 }
 return 0;
```